# Using CMPH in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, perfect-hash

I would like to use minimal perfect hash from [CMPH](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/index.html). Any idea how can I use it on a VC++ project?

I created a new project using VC++ 2008 Express Edition here and add the header and source files but it output compilation errors.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CMPH, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>wingetopt.c
1>vstack.c
1>vqueue.c
1>select.c
1>.\select.c(24) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline' –
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the project is delivered source-only, so you will have to download the source code and build it with your platform's compiler. When that is done, you will have `cmph.h` and an associated library.

You will then have to edit your Visual Studio project and add the header file to your project or put the location into your include path, and edit the project to put the location where the .lib is.

Comment: Can you update your original post with those problems? The formatting in comments is very broken.

Comment: Sorry first time using stackoverflow, thought I could post an reply easily but turns out not.